# Use shapeless Mapper without having to specify the result type

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation

This seems to be a classic question for developers used to Scala type-level programming, but I couldn't find (or I don't know how to search for) a solution or pattern for this. Suppose I have a class like this:

```
abstract class TypedTest[Args <: HList](implicit val optMapper: Mapped[Args, Option]) {
  type OptArgs = optMapper.Out

  def options: OptArgs // to be implemented by subclasses
}
```

I want users of this class to instantiate it with an `HList` type parameter (`Args`) and the class provides a method to retrieve an `HList` instance containing an instance of each specified type inside an `Option` (`OptArgs`). I'm using shapeless [Mapped](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/ops/hlists.scala#L60) type class for this. Note that I *don't* have an instance of `Args` to provide at instantiation time.

This code doesn't work, as the compiler doesn't infer the concrete type of `OptArgs` and even an obviously correct implementation such as `def options = HNil` yields a compilation error. The same code using the Aux pattern:

```
abstract class TypedTest[Args <: HList, OptArgs <: HList](implicit val optMapper: Mapped.Aux[Args, Option, OptArgs]) {
  def options: OptArgs
}
```

This forces me to specify both lists at instantiation time, which makes the external API needlessly verbose. Is there an workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is my understanding, but I'm not 100% sure and will be happy to stand corrected.

The type member `TypedTest.OptArgs` is not an abstract type but a type alias. It is the same type for all subclasses of `TypedTest` – an alias for `Mapped[Args, Option].Out`, which is an abstract type and cannot be unified with any type but itself. When a subclass is created, the type member `OptArgs` is not overridden.

It becomes more clear when using `Mapped.Aux` with an existential type for `Out0`, which is IIUC more or less equivalent to the above:

```scala
abstract class TypedTest[Args <: HList](
    implicit val optMapper: Mapped.Aux[Args, Option, T] forSome { type T }) {

  type OptArgs = optMapper.Out

  def options: OptArgs // to be implemented by subclasses
}

val intTest = new TypedTest[Int :: HNil] {
  def options = Some(1) :: HNil
}

Error:(18, 29) type mismatch;
found   : shapeless.::[Some[Int],shapeless.HNil]
required: this.OptArgs
  (which expands to)  T
    def options = Some(1) :: HNil
```

Unfortunately I'm not aware of any possible solution, except adding `Out` as a type parameter or defining `OptArgs` as an abstract type and specifying it explicitly in each subclass.

Comment: I did not intend `OptArgs` to be an abstract type, but rather a path dependent type - dependent on the value of `optMapper`. Although I defined `OptArgs` as a type alias, I could omit that definition and just write `def options: optMapper.Out`. Path-dependent types can be used meaningfully, even when defined as abstract types - that's what the definition of `Mapper.Aux` does to "convert" the path-dependent type to a type parameter. It may be that there is no solution in this case, though.